# performance doesn't scale fully while cpu is 100% in each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I implemented a high-performance algorithm and I'm quite happy that I managed to make it four times faster using seven threads instead of one. It takes less than one hour now. I was just wondering what might be the cause(s) for not scaling up seven times. Both in the single-threaded and multithreaded case, the cpu usage is 100% for each thread. In my fantasy, that counters every argument:

- more threads makes memory access slower -> but cpu is the bottleneck
- synchronized/blocking queue access makes it slower -> but cpu is the bottleneck

etc.

Also importantly, the total work did not increase because of parallellization.

How can I get out of my fantasy?

edit: each thread runs a loop and threads don't stop (and start) before the computation is finished.

Comment: Google [`overhead of multithreading`](https://www.google.com/search?q=overhead+of+multithreading&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: How many cores does your computer have?

Comment: @tom 8 cores (quadcore with two threads per core). Intel i7-4770. When I don't run the algorithm, the computer is idle.

Comment: Hyperthreading doesn't mean you'd get two threads running at the same time, all the time. Only when the code being run is suitably waiting for specific things. Getting 4x out of four cores is very good.

Comment: In fact, CPU-heavy loads are exactly the case where hyperthreading *won't* give you both threads on full. The idea behind hyperthreading is that if an operation is waiting on memory (or some other resource), another thread can get work done. If there's not much memory usage to block on, hyperthreading won't do anything, and your quad core will have four physical threads.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading#Performance_claims) says claimed performance is only 15–30% better, citing a [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20121019025809/http://www.intel.com/technology/itj/2002/volume06issue01/vol6iss1_hyper_threading_technology.pdf) and [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-determine-the-effectiveness-of-hyper-threading-technology-with-an-application/) by Intel.

Comment: You guys are correct. I ran it with 4 threads and total time is only 8% slower than with 7 threads, even though processor monitor shows 55% instead of 95%.. Solved!

Comment: See also [turbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) and note there's probably no special column in your profile for memory accesses and that they count as "cpu busy".